# Logical reduction of code to a one-line expression

Tags: javascript, logic

This one seems to be real. How can I reduce this to one if statement?

```
    let combined = true;

    if(earlyCallback){
      combined = self.allChildBlocksCompleted;
    }

    if (self.parent && combined) {  // I want to put everything here

    }
```

Is this correct?

```
 if(self.parent || (earlyCallback && self.allChildBlocksCompleted)){

  }
```

I think it's right but I can't tell right now.

Comment: yeah, my solution is wrong, because self.parent is always required to be true, so the `logical or` does not work.

Comment: Isn't it just `self.parent && (earlyCallback && combined)`?

Comment: @Andy that's what I thought too, but the problem with your solution is that if earlyCallback is false, then the if statement evaluates to false. But I desire a case where if earlyCallback is false, then the if statement still has a chance to evaluate to true.

Comment: lol why is this so hard haha

Comment: my original code (at the top of the OP) is correct as it is. I just am curious about how to reduce it since I know it can be down with at least one fewer variables.

Comment: If someone can name a logical rule that applies to this scenario, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer do it like below:

```js
if (self.parent && (earlyCallback ? self.allChildBlocksCompleted : true )) { }
```

Comment: I think this is correct, but I wish it could be further simplified

Comment: but wouldn't `earlyCallback` always end up true then?

Comment: earlyCallback is an independent variable in this answer

Comment: I swear there is a way to simplify this further

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to the accepted answer:

```
if (self.parent && (!earlyCallback || self.allChildBlocksCompleted)) {
```

You might consider this simpler than other answers that require the hard-coded literal `true` and the ternary operator. It's also shorter by a few characters:

```
if (self.parent && (earlyCallback ? self.allChildBlocksCompleted : true)) {
```

You can "simplify" it further by exchanging one "or" for an extra not and an "and" using De Morgan:

```
if (self.parent && !(earlyCallback && !self.allChildBlocksCompleted)) {
```

Comment: ah yes that looks like it